# Tree for narrow strip

Tags: identification, trees, plant-recommendations

I’m in Melbourne, Australia, and interested in a tree for a narrow strip along the fence line. The tree is ultimately to obscure a neighboring property. It doesn’t matter if it takes years to grow as other trees already do the job, but those will ultimately die out. I’ve attached a photo of the fence line area. 
[image]

(Probably should’ve said shrubs instead of tree, as those also get quite tall)

Answer (score 3):

Forget trees Simon.  Possibly woody vines.  No tree should be planted in that strip. No shrubs for that matter.  Where is this photo of the fence line?

There are lots of great alternatives for privacy that you can do with dimensional lumber.  I would need to see the line and angle of sight of your neighbors. No tree will ever be happy in that space, trust me.

I see a few spot lights.  Have you considered planting a tree in a pot?  A few pots, a few trees; Serviceberry would be happy, multi trunked, gorgeous small tree and thrive in a 50 gallon heavy pot with drainage hole and using just potting soil.  Vine maple another good choice.  How cold are your winters?

Comment: Serviceberry will not do well in Australia. No winter for the required dormancy period

Comment: Ugh...I've got to check Australia's zone.  This year having snow threw me I guess!  So he should be able to grow in big big pots whatever small trees he desires without worrying about freezes...long term freezes?

Comment: @kevinsky what about the vine maples?  They COULD be planted in that strip as long as one would reconfigure the fence and deck to fit the tree as it grew?

Comment: given the chequered past of gardeners introducing exotic foreign species that don't behave I think an Australian species would be easier to source and less potential trouble